# How can I improve the speed of computing region intersection?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, computational-geometry, regions

I have a polygon defined by a list of nodes (x,y). I want to cut the polygon by a horizontal line at position y = a and get the new polygon above the position y = a. I am using the RegionIntersect function, but it seems very slow if I want to combine the function with Manipulate function as well. Is there any way to improve my code to get better speed?

```
R2 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 750}}] ;
Manipulate[
R1 = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <=  300, a <= y <= 700}, {x, y} ];
R3 = RegionIntersection[R1, R2];
RegionPlot[R3], {a, 1, 499}]
```

Comment: May be you can put `R2 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 750}}];` outside `Manipulate`, so that it doesn't get evaluated everytime `a` changes.

Comment: It doesn't improve that much. The slider is not as smooth as I want it to be.

Answer (score 5):

It's a lot faster to find the intersection with a `Polygon` than with an `ImplicitRegion`.  In your case you can write your region succinctly as a simple `Polygon`

```
DynamicModule[{R1, R2, R3},
 R2 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 750}}];
 Manipulate[
  R1 = Polygon[{{0, a}, {300, a}, {300, 700}, {0, 700}}];
  R3 = RegionIntersection[R1, R2];
  RegionPlot[R3,
   PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Thread[First@R2]],
  {a, 1, 499}]
 ]
```

[image]

If you want it faster, you can skip using `RegionPlot`, since your `Region` is just another `Polygon`.  Something like this gives a good approximation of `RegionPlot`

```
DynamicModule[{R1, R2, R3},
 R2 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 750}}];
 Manipulate[
  R1 = Polygon[{{0, a}, {300, a}, {300, 700}, {0, 700}}];
  R3 = RegionIntersection[R1, R2];
  Graphics[{
    RGBColor[0.36, 0.5, 0.7],
    EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.36, .5, .7]]],
    Opacity[0.4],
    R3},
   PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Thread@First@R2,
   Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 5/6],
  {a, 1, 499}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

On my machine doing everything in one step and discretizing the regions appears to smooth things out a bit.

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  DiscretizeRegion@
   RegionIntersection[
    DiscretizeRegion@
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, 500}, {0, 750}}], 
    DiscretizeRegion@
     ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= 300, a <= y <= 700}, {x, y}]]], {a, 0, 500}]
```

Comment: it actually smoothed things a bit, why was that ? I would have thought DiscretizeRegion would give the computer more work to do thus slower things down !

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but my guess would be that evaluating the expression symbolically is sufficiently more complicated then determining the `RegionIntersection` numerically.

Comment: I added an option, it seems to improve a bit
      MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]

Answer (score 1):

```
R1 = ImplicitRegion[{0<=x<=300,a<=y<=700},{x,y}];
R2 = Polygon[{{0,0},{300,0},{300,500},{0,750}}];
ineq = RegionMember[RegionIntersection[R1,R2],{x,y}]//Simplify//Rest
With[{ineq = ineq},
  Manipulate[RegionPlot[ineq,{x,0,300},{y,0,700},PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],{a,1,499}]]
```